# Неявные графики matplotlib python

Tags: python, график, искусственный-интеллект, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется функция двух переменных (решающая функция):

```
def dec_func(self, x, y):
    res = 0
    for i, w in enumerate(self.W):
        res += w * self.F[i](Point(x, y))
    return res
```

Нужно построить график этой функции, когда res = 0. Т.е. нужно из списка X для каждого x получить такие y, чтобы при выполнении функции, результат был равен 0.

UPD:

Есть реализованная функция, которая по заданным X может получить примерно верные Y (с определенной точностью):

```
def plot_data(self, start=-15, end=15, step=1):
    X = [i for i in range(start, end, step)]
    Y = []
    x_to_remove = []
    for x in X:
        k = 0
        y_old = 0
        step = 0.05
        old_res = self.dec_func(x, y_old)
        while abs(old_res) > 0.01:
            if k > 3000:
                break
            k += 1
            y = y_old + step
            res = self.dec_func(x, y)
            if abs(old_res) > abs(res):
                y_old = y
                step *= 1.2
            else:
                y_old = y
                step = -step / 2
            old_res = res
        if k > 3000:
            print(y_old, x, old_res)
            x_to_remove.append(x)
        else:
            Y.append(y_old)
    for x in x_to_remove:
        X.remove(x)
    return X, Y
```

Но проблема в том, что данная реализация не позволяет получить несколько значений y для одного x.

Comment: Можно больше данных по коду? Что за объекты `self.W` и `self.F`? `Point` - это класс? Из какой он библиотеки, или это ваш собственный класс или функция? И что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @mkkik, то, что находится внутри функции в принципе не важно. Я это просто для примера вставил. Главное, что есть функция, которая принимает на вход х, у и возвращает результат. Не получается построить график функции dec_func(x, y) = 0

Comment: Чтобы понять, почему не получается, надо смотреть на участок кода, где вы строите график.

Comment: @mkkik, дело в том, что я не знаю как его построить.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: @mkkik, у меня есть один работающий способ получения нужных x и y. Но он меня не устраивает, т.к. не учитывается то, что для 1 x может быть 2 y.

Comment: Возможно можно просто вычислить на выбранной сетке все значения, потом [выбросить не нулевые точки, используя `pyplot.contour()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2484527/4279) Вопрос старый посмотрите похожие ссылки—сейчас возможно проще решение существует.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо! Получилось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно нарисовать график для подобных функций.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from numpy import arange
from numpy import meshgrid

delta = 0.025
xrange = arange(-50.0, 50.0, delta)
yrange = arange(-50.0, 50.0, delta)
X, Y = meshgrid(xrange, yrange)
F = dec_func(X, Y) 
matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, F, [0])
```